# vpnc problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vpn, vpnc

I am trying to connect to vpn using the following command

`sudo vpnc-connect ~/vpn.conf`

In `vpn.conf` I have the following configs

```
IPSec gateway XXXXXXX
IPSec ID XXXXXX
IPSec secret XXXXXX
Xauth username XXXXXXX
Xauth password XXXXXXX
```

I am able to connect to vpn successfuly, but after that I am unable to connect to internet. I have to disconnect vpn before connecting to internet. This method used to work in ubuntu 16.04. I have recently installed ubuntu 18.04. This method does not work anymore. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a routing problem.

You should try 'route -n'.

It will show you're routing everything through the VPN.

Then adapt your routing table.